# Assigning patch values from raster data in NetLogo

Tags: gis, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I am attempting to assign values to patches in NetLogo based upon raster values: 0, 1, and 2. These patches need only relate to the values of my raster, which does display properly using a greyscale, and then 'paint' themselves the colors blue, green, and white, respectively.

This raster data loads fine using the gis extension. Following gis:load-dataset, I attempt to use the apply-raster command and ifelse in order to give options based on the values. I believe I am misusing a boolean operator but very few examples online are as extensive as what I am attempting.

```
patches-own [value]

; Draws raster dataset (terrain of each Millenium) 
to display-terrain
  gis:paint terrain 62

 ask patches [
  (ifelse
    value = 0 [
      set pcolor blue
    ]
    value = 1 [
      set pcolor green
    ]
    ; elsecommands
    [
      set pcolor white
  ])
]
end
```

I currently cannot tell if the values are properly assigned and keep receiving the error that 'ifelse expects this to be a command block' so I assume the formatting is incorrect and/or a value association is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are using it exactly as the documentation says to use it, but you probably don't have the current version. The multiple choice `ifelse` is brand new in NetLogo v6.0.4. You need to explicitly include the `cf` extension and you need the extension name when calling the new `ifelse` syntax.

Earlier versions of NetLogo won't do this at all. The syntax you have is for v6.1 which has been released only in the last couple of weeks.

Try this for v6.0.4:

```
extensions [cf]
patches-own [value]

to testme
  clear-all
  ask patches [ set value one-of [0 1 2] ]
  ask patches [
  (cf:ifelse
    value = 0 [
      set pcolor blue
    ]
    value = 1 [
      set pcolor green
    ]
    ; elsecommands
    [
      set pcolor white
    ])
  ]
end
```